# Vue default selected option on object

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I know that the `v-model` data should be the same as the default option but what I do when I have things setup like this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      user: {
        usertype: {},
    }
}

<select v-model="user.usertype" class="btn btn-secondary d-flex header-input">
<option
v-for="(usertype, index) in usertypes"
:key="index"
:value="{value: usertype['short_desc_'+locale], max_user: usertype['max_user']}"
>{{usertype['short_desc_'+locale]}}</option>
```

I tried adding another option disabled `value=""` but it didn't select it as default. more like, it doesn't show. when I open up the dropdown menu, the first item is checked already but it does not show when its closed. any help is appreciated :)

**Edit: Structure of usertypes**

```
[{"id":1,"short_desc_de":"Mann","short_desc_en":"Men","min_user":1,"max_user":1,"created_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06","updated_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06"},{"id":2,"short_desc_de":"Frau","short_desc_en":"Woman","min_user":1,"max_user":1,"created_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06","updated_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06"},...]
```

Comment: Could you post the structure of your `usertypes` as well?

Comment: its an empty object just for storing data, couldve as well used an array. Edit: Oh usertypeS, yes wait a sec

Comment: But then of course your v-for loop will produce no output. What do you want the list to contain when `user.usertype` is unset? It's not very clear from the question.

Comment: No i just spelled them poorly, usertypeS is a prop , usertype is but an empty object to store the chosen option. It does produce a dropdown, but no selected default option works

Comment: Just for clarification: I'd like to have a default value upon visiting the page. Right now, there is none. Its just a blank field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of adding an additional `<option>` element was good, but instead of setting `value=""`, you need to match the default state of `user.usertype`, which is an empty object. So if you set the attribute `:value="{}"`, you'll get the desired result.

*(on a sidenote unrelated to the technics, your first usertype should probably be "Man" instead of plural "Men" in English, or maybe you'd be even better of with "male"/"female")*

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      usertype: {}
    },
    usertypes: [{"id":1,"short_desc_de":"Mann","short_desc_en":"Men","min_user":1,"max_user":1,"created_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06","updated_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06"},{"id":2,"short_desc_de":"Frau","short_desc_en":"Woman","min_user":1,"max_user":1,"created_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06","updated_at":"2019-09-19 08:07:06"}],
    locale: 'en'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="user.usertype" class="btn btn-secondary d-flex header-input">
  <option v-if="!Object.keys(user.usertype).length" :value="{}" disabled>please choose one</option>
  <option
  v-for="(usertype, index) in usertypes"
  :key="index"
  :value="{value: usertype['short_desc_'+locale], max_user: usertype['max_user']}"
  >{{usertype['short_desc_'+locale]}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>{{user.usertype}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ^^, on a last note: What about an array? I get the gist of an object now, but how would you approach this matter if it were an array?

Comment: Just use an empty array: `:value="[]"`